# Why did Delacourt act the way she did toward the end of Elysium?

Tags: elysium

MASSIVE SPOILER WARNING:

> Toward the end of *Elysium*, Delacourt (Jodie Foster's character) confronts a newly-reconstructed Kruger for the mess he's made of the situation, but he's moved beyond her petty concerns; he knows that if he can subdue Costa (Matt Damon), hook him up to the Torus and use the reboot program for himself, he can make himself the only legal citizen of Elysium and the habitat will become his personal playground. So, with Delacourt more hindrance than help toward that goal, he stabs her in the neck and dumps her in the same supply closet holding Frey and her daughter. Frey tries to staunch the bleeding and patch her up long enough for help to come (there's a med-pod just the other side of the door), but Delacourt refuses her help and dies.

At first, it appeared to be...

> ... a purely selfish move. Delacourt's completely lost control of the situation, her coup's failed, and no matter what happens as a result of Kruger and Max running around, she's bound to lose her job and probably her life. Better to die now with some semblance of honor rather than fight to hang on to life only to be executed or exiled in shame.

However, on reflection...

> ... there may be a racist or at least an elitist slant to her decision. Delacourt (and many other Elysium citizens, like Armadyne CEO John Carlyle) spends most of the movie demonstrating her belief that the people on Earth are a sub-race, not human, certainly not anywhere near the implicit worth of a citizen of Elysium. This refusal may therefore be as much about who's offering it as what it means for the rest of the life she might have, and shows that Delacourt is truly irredeemable, if she has such disdain for an Earth resident that she'd rather die than receive help.

The flip side may be true as well...

> ...after spending the entire movie detaining, deporting and killing Earth residents as illegal immigrants, and the mess she's made on Elysium, Delacourt may think herself unworthy of Frey's compassion, someone she might well have let die if the situation were reversed. If this were the case, it would be somewhat of a redemption for Delacourt's character rather than a final damning.

Are there any definitive sources, or evidence I haven't mentioned, for any of these conclusions?

Comment: I think that answers would be speculation, but I still like the question.

Comment: Doesn't she say "no more," when she turns away first aid? I wondered what she meant by that.

Comment: There were simply too many plot holes, missing facts, and incomplete character development to be 100% sure about much of this.

Comment: My view was the latter thing you postulated. @ForceFlow  If you thought that was illogical, I guess you'd *detest* Oblivion, which I viewed as a steaming pile of ..illogic.  The other night I was postulating an answer to a question on it, but felt compelled to mention some of the things that had me thinking "What the huh..?"  Just in that brief time, I counted 21 aspects of it that made *no sense at all!*

Answer (score 1):

Since ELysium was written as an original screenplay and not derived from any other narrative this answer will be speculation: It seems that Delacourt's "change of heart" was attempt by the filmmakers to give her a range of emotions and character that was lacking throughout the remainder of the film. Her sudden change of heart is completely incongruous and when it occurs there's simply been no foundation created to support it.

Unfortunately, as with the remainder of the film, character motivations and logic are so skewed and the plot possesses some many holes and contrivances that attempting to discern them is probably an exercise in futility. Perhaps if there is eve a novelization for the film, these missing threads will be found and woven into the story. For now, one can only assume that the motives either existed in a longer version of the screenplay and were cut for time or pacing. Or that they never existed and this scene was a last-ditch attempt to somehow humanize the antagonist in the end.

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't a change of heart. She turned away first aid because she knew that she would be caught trying to overthrow Elysium. She bribed Carlyle to reprogram Elysium's computer system so that she could become president. If she had survived the injury she sustained when Kruger stabbed her and penetrated her jugular - which is highly unlikely unless she made it to a medical swiftly - she would have been executed for treason, or jailed for life.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that when Carlyle got shot, he didn't act like death was the biggest thing. Also since the data transfer killed Max, wouldn't it kill Carlyle as well? That got me to think that there is some kind of hidden theme concerning immortality. Seems like the rich just want to die and considering they're practically immortal in Elysium, it just begs more questions.

Comment: The data transfer killed him because he'd stolen the data and there were security measures in place. Carlyle would have been able to transfer it without any risk because it was his data, and was supposed to be in his head.